# display two pivot tables using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pivottable.js

I am trying to create two pivot tables using pivottable.js to show payroll hours

the desired result would be like this:

Payroll for location 1

```
foo
bar
biz
```

Payroll for location 2

```
bad
bash 
bin
```

obviously in the pivottable.js display form which I cannot recreate here

however, the pivottable only shows one for the page and it is either location 1 or location 2

I dont know enough about javascript or html to understand what I am doing wrong here, it seems like a simple problem that I just am not seeing. this is all within a php file.

here is the code I am using for the php file

```
$pageStart = '<html>
<head>
    <title>Payroll</title>
    <!-- c3 and d3 scripts and jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PivotTable.js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery/pivottable/dist/pivot.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/pivottable/dist/pivot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/c3_renderers.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {font-family: Verdana;}
    </style>

    <!-- mobile support -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p> Location 1 payroll hours
    <script type="text/javascript">
// This loads the payroll hours for location 1
// no derived attributes
var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;
var renderers = $.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers,
$.pivotUtilities.c3_renderers);
$(function(NB){NB,
        $("#output").pivotUI(
        ' . $json . ',
        {rows: ["Name"],
        cols: ["Hours_type", "Date"],
        aggregatorName: "Sum",
        vals: ["Hours"],}
        );
 });
 </script>
 <br>
 <p> location 2 Payroll Hours
 <script>
$(function(SV){
        $("#output").pivotUI(SV,
        ' . $json2 . ',
        {rows: ["Name"],
        cols: ["Hours_type", "Date"],
        aggregatorName: "Sum",
        vals: ["Hours"],}
        );
 })
    </script>

    <div id="output" style="margin: 30px;"></div>

</body>
</html>';

print $pageStart;
```

the `$json` and `$json2` are mysql functions that pull the data for the pivottable to display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $("#output") for both tables, then one will overwrite the other.

Comment: so the second $("#output") should just be renamed to something like $("#output2")

Comment: Even after I renamed the output, I still returned only one pivottable, then it hit me that the reason was because I needed to place two seperate `<div>...</div>` so it would end up looking like`<div id="output" style="margin: 30px;"></div>` and another line saying `<div id="output2" style="margin: 30px;"></div>` so thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You would need two different tags with different ids like :

Reference first table in output and second in output1